# Different apparent brightness of a distant star from a moving frame - an apparent paradox

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, lorentz-symmetry, relative-motion

Consider a stationary star at a distance $L$ from the Earth.

A spaceship at Earth moving with velocity $v$ towards the star will find the star to be at a distance of $\dfrac{L}\gamma$ in its own frame.

But it won't actually see the star at that distance since the speed of light is finite.

The light that it will get at that instant will be from a star that was at distance $\dfrac{Lc}{\gamma(c-v)}$ which is $>L$.

At $v=0.6c$, $\dfrac{Lc}{\gamma(c-v)}=2L$.

Therefore, the spaceship will see the star $0.25$ times as bright as an observer on the Earth.

But this is unexpected since both spaceship and the Earth are bathed in the same starlight and if anything, the observer on the Earth sees the spaceship gather more photons due to its motion.

How to resolve this apparent paradox?

Comment: You can't do special relativity just using gamma!  If you really want to know what stars look like when you are traveling quickly relative to them, I would suggest this source. https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s2-05/2-05.htm  - but I'm not saying it will be an easy ride!  To summarize: using the correct theory, there is no paradox.

Comment: @m4r35n357 Thank you for the great link. Could you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I don't feel it qualifies as an answer because I am just referring to somebody else's hard work!  If a mod asks me I will though.

Comment: if you liked that link there are lots of other good ones in that book.  You can read the whole thing online, but I ended up buying it.

Comment: @m4r35n357 Thank you! I will check.

Comment: @m4r35n357 Since no one else has answered, I request you to answer it so that it can be useful for future visitors. Since you will give due credit, the question of taking benefit from someone else's hard work doesn't arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do special relativity just using gamma! If you really want to know what stars look like when you are traveling quickly relative to them, you need to use the correct method.

I would suggest [this source](https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s2-05/2-05.htm) - the maths is as simple as it can be, but I'm not saying it will be an easy ride! The meat of the answer begins at the paragraph: "Meanwhile, Einstein's 1905 paper on the electrodynamics of moving bodies . . .", but it is well worth reading the whole thing.  To summarize: using the correct theory, there is no paradox.

Answer (score 1):

The star will look dimmer because to the moving observer the star is aging slower, so to this observer, the star emits less energy per unit of time. Also, the total number of photons each observe between two events will be the same, but they will disagree on how much time has passed between the two events and about their synchronization